# Are questions about connecting smartphones to computers on-topic?

Tags: support, reopen-request, off-topic, scope

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/654079/how-to-transfer-photos-from-a-galaxy-siii-to-a-mac-computer) asks about connecting a smartphone to a computer and transfering files. It was put on-hold as off-topic.

[The list of on-topic subjects](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), linked on the very on-hold message, says questions about "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones" are off-topic, "**except insofar as they interface with your computer**".

Isn't this question ontopic as it asks about connecting a smartphone to the PC and transfering files? Or is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: it is ontopic, but hits the lack-of-research bit

Comment: @Sathya Then why close it as off-topic? It is signaling others that it is off-topic when in fact it is not.

Comment: you should ask that to the people who closed it as offtopic.

Comment: Let's be honest it was migrated from SO's meta website and is vague at best.  It's not off topic but the question is not good but currently has answers

Answer (score 13):

I have always interpreted any questions that involve interfacing a device (such as a smartphone, iPhone, iPad, etc.) with a computer or actions that require a computer to interact with a device to be completely on topic. Examples might be how to back up an iPhone with iTunes on Windows, or how to Restore a specific firmware file to a device through iTunes. I'd even consider a question about iTunes WiFi syncing to be reasonably on topic if the user showed enough research to strongly indicate that it was not the device or network at fault.

I don't think that particular question is a role model of questions, but I wouldn't call it off-topic.